# Server error 500 when adding .htaccess

Tags: php

I'm having a problem when adding .htaccess. It doesn't works with a htaccess file. when I upgrade from PHP 5.2.x to 5.6.X  I receive **Error 500** in old version working perfectly.

> Note: my httpd.conf (LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so) -- still the same problem, any code I write in .htaccess facing the same error.
>
> Some think with configuration to solve it.

Below my  .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: _'It doesn't work'_ is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: 'It doesn't work' mean **Server error!**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
**Error 500**
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

Answer (score 1):

Your condition says if it is not a file then your rule says whatever it is is a PHP file?

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
                        ^
```

That's invalid and causes the error that you get. If something is not a file, how can it be a php file? it just doesn't exist.

You have to point it to an existing file in this case. Something like

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```